# PHP not working in Apache2 after system upgrade

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, 9.10, php, apache2

Recently upgraded my system from Karmic to Lucid. This involved Apache and PHP being updated I believe.

Now my server is unable to handle PHP files, any navigation to them is triggering downloading rather than parsing.

The PHP module is still loaded in Apache mods-enabled and I have 
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` in my httpd.conf.

There are no meaningful messages in Apache access or error logs so I am stumped.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`/var/log/apache2/error.log` should show a line like the below if PHP was succesfully loaded:

> [Tue Aug 30 12:53:36 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

Pay attention to the date, if it's something from 2009, you've misconfigured something.

`AddType` is useless, you need to use:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

See also the [installation instructions on php.net for Apache 2.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php).

You should not have a need to add that manually, the package `libapache2-mod-php5` installs `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf` containing:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Since it's a conffile, it's possible that it's not installed with the upgrade. To fix that *purge* it and then install it again:

```
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

To enable PHP, you have to run:

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

Restart the webserver after:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Other things to do:

- check for conflicting settings in `/etc/apache2`.
- have you built Apache from source?
- Run `sudo apache2ctl configtest` to check your configuration for syntax errors
- Open http://localhost/server-info to check the loaded configuration and modules. The `status` module must be loaded for that. If you're running a remote server, you need to add yourself to the `Allow from` list in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf` and restart the server afterwards

Comment: Brilliant. AFK right now, but will test this out tonight. Thanks.

Comment: Purged and reinstalled, the module is loaded in mods-enabled, but I am still having the same issue...I can't find anything that would be conflicted and the include for the conf files is definitely present in apache.conf. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Jivings: some debugging ideas added

Comment: Still unable to figure it out. However I have discovered something even more curious. It seems that PHP is working fine for one of the Virtual Hosts that is set up, though all it does is define a documentRoot at /var/www. How is this possible?!

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct anyway, because it was very useful. Thanks Lekensteyn.

Comment: Bah, I found what the problem was, see my answer...

Comment: You will still need to flush your browser's cache and restart apache.

Comment: Thank you @Francesco. It working when I changed to Firefox from Chrome, so I believe it was a cache issue for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Well after nothing else worked and Apache was getting very confusing I finally just purged all of the Apache packages and reinstalled them.

Seems to be working fine now, who knows what was wrong with it....

**EDIT**

I found out what was wrong when I was setting up my Apache configuration settings again.
[This blog entry][1] explains it.

Turns out that although the userdir module is not actively in use, the rest of the sites files reside in my ~/public_html folder, and php was being disabled for everything in there.

I guess this must have been a recent addition to the php module which wasn't present in my Karmic settings.

Comment: That should be related to a configuration issue. On upgrades, no files in `/etc` are copied afaik (at least, someone had an issue with `/etc/init.d/apache2` not being created on reinstall, only on purge+install)

Comment: Strange that it worked before my system upgrade then...

Comment: likely a feature change then. You can't expect every upgrade to respect old configuration settings. Some modifications would make sense for the majority but not for some others.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for helping me get to the bottom of it anyway, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

the `php5.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` has a few lines at the bottom that keep php from executing inside of a user directory, so depending on your configuration, this could be your issue also. You can just comment these lines out and apache2 reload